# Json format to request to Java Server

Tags: unity, java, json

I have this class in java, I'm using Jersey.

```
 @Path("/bandas")
 public class BandaResource {

static private Map<Integer, Banda> bandasMap=someSource();

@GET    
@Produces({ "application/json" })
public List<Banda> getBandas()
 {
    return new ArrayList<Banda>(bandasMap.values());
 }



@POST
@Consumes("text/xml")
@Produces("text/plain")
          public String adicionaBanda(Banda banda) {
           banda.setId(bandasMap.size() + 1);
           bandasMap.put(banda.getId(), banda);
           return banda.getNome() + " adicionado.";
    }
}
```

In Unity when I request all the information I get an answer from server:

```
 URL url = new URL ( "http://localhost:8080/restful-exemplo/rest/bandas" );
 WWW www = new WWW(url);
```

Debug.Log (www.data) returns:

*{"banda":[{"anoDeFormacao":"1968","id":"1","nome":"Led Zeppelin"},{"anoDeFormacao":"1973","id":"2","nome":"AC/DC"}]}*

But I want to send, I don't have any idea how but I tried:

```
 string JSON=" {\"nome\":\"Teste\", \"anoDeFormacao\":\"1988\",\"id\":\"4\"}";

    Hashtable postHeader = new Hashtable();     
    postHeader.Add("Content-Type", "text/json");


    UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    WWW request = new WWW(url, encoding.GetBytes(JSON.ToCharArray()), HashtableToDictionary<string, string>(postHeader));
```

Well, it returns a error (WWW Error: 415 Unsupported Media Type
), is the idea correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Java method is declared with `@Consumes("text/xml")`. That means it expects the MIME-type `text/xml` and XML-encoded data.

But on the Unity-side you are using a header to set the content-type to `text/json` and send JSON-encoded data. The result is a `451 Unsupported Media Type` HTTP error, [just like the documentation says](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs-javax.jax-rs/2.0.1/javax/ws/rs/Consumes.html).

Make sure the Unity-side sets the content-type header to the same MIME-type the server method consumes. When you want to use JSON, then that would be `application/json` ([`text/json` is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type), but might still work). If you would like to use `text/xml` instead, you also need to format your data as XML on the Unity-side.